# Unchecked boxes using checkboxGroupInput in Shiny

Tags: r, if-statement, checkbox, input, shiny

**EDIT:** My original question asked about `checkboxInput()`, but I've updated to `checkboxGroupInput()` to better reflect my problem...

I am trying to get my Shiny app to do one of two things based on the (un)checked status of a **checkboxGroupInput**.

When the boxes are checked, I can get my code to work. However, I can't figure out how to make **unchecking all boxes** lead to a unique result.

How do I do this?

This [google groups question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shiny-discuss/4kmLgnjX_10/SSSXewGj0rsJ) asked this 4+ years ago, but the response then was that this is simply a bug. I'm assuming this has been addressed since??

**Below is a reproducible example**.
 - In this example, unchecking the box leads to an error reading "Error in if: argument is of length zero."

```
library(shiny)

ui <-  fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "test.check", label = "", choices = "Uncheck For 2", selected = "Uncheck For 2"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "test")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$test <- renderPrint({
    if(input$test.check == "Uncheck For 2") {
      1
    } else {
      2
    }
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there perhaps an "if.unchecked" type of function I can use?

- I've tried `is.null` after the `else` statement with the same result as the above example....

Comment: try `is.null` this way : `if(!is.null(input$test.check) && input$test.check == "Uncheck For 2")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's code that works:

```
library(shiny)

ui <-  fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId="test.check", label="", choices="Uncheck For 2", selected="Uncheck For 2"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "test")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test <- renderPrint({
    if(!is.null(input$test.check)) {
      1
    } else{
      2
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! So is this simply just a boolean test??. Also, I want to use `checkboxGroupInput` so that I can provide a title for my input (which `checkboxInput` does not have an argument for).

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase my question as how to select an action based on all checks of a checkboxGroupInput being unchecked....

Comment: Ok in that case using `is.null()` works. I modified my response to do that with `checkboxGroupInput`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious, though, as to why using `is.null()` for the `else` part of the statement *doesn't* work, but using `!is.null` in the `if` statement does...???

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. Couldn't figure out why myself.